# Script working via terminal but not with cron

Tags: python, cron

This test script is the exact scenario which is replicating my problem.

```
import atomac, time

noront = atomac.getAppRefByBundleId(BUNDLE_ID)
noront.activate()
time.sleep(5)
ax = {'AXRole' : 'AXButton'}
toggle = noront.findAllR(**ax)
print "Toggle is ", toggle
with open("/tmp/test1.txt", 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(str(toggle))
```

When i run this script in the terminal i get the output

```
python /Users/user/Desktop/test.py
```

After running when i do
cat /tmp/test1.txt

```
[<atomac.AXClasses.NativeUIElement AXButton u'I agree'>, <atomac.AXClasses.NativeUIElement AXButton u'I Accept'>, <atomac.AXClasses.NativeUIElement AXButton u'Pr P'>, <atomac.AXClasses.NativeUIElement AXButton None>, <atomac.AXClasses.NativeUIElement AXButton None>, <atomac.AXClasses.NativeUIElement AXButton None>]
```

However, i added a cron entry for the same.

```
* * * * * sleep 10; python /Users/user/Desktop/test.py
```

after running when i do

```
cat /tmp/test1.txt
[]
```

it returns the empty set. Can someone help me why elements are not getting detected when i run via cron ?

Is it something to do with the permissions ?

Comment: It might be useful to add some logging to the script in order to see what's going wrong. You can add this line to the cron definition: `* * * * * sleep 10; python /Users/user/Desktop/test.py >> /tmp/cron.log`

Comment: Yes. i tried adding that . i am getting "toggle is []". I am sure that the cron is triggering. But the question here is , why its not detecting ui elements when ran via cron ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running your cron job every second. You can check the date of `/tmp/test1.txt` to make sure it is being recreated all the time.

I also think you should also load the `.profile` before, something like this:

```
30 14 * * * . .profile; python /Users/user/Desktop/test.py
```

Comment: i am sure that script is getting executed. But not sure why its not detecting the UI element when ran via cron

Comment: And i dont have bash profile. What you are suggesting to keep inside bash profile ?